# Apache: Access denied to /

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, selinux

I have disabled `selinux` with:

```
setenforce 0 
selinux=disabled
```

in `/etc/selinux/config` Does anyone knows if i have to `label` or `chcon` any dir to solve that error:

```
error [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied
```

I'm running centOS6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check file and directory permissions of this file and all parent directories.  They need to typically be world readable.

Often times this happens if you put some files in a home directory, but the home dir is still at it's default of 700.  Run `chmod 755 /home/you` to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

The code below might help you. Had the same problem with SELinux:

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /you_virtual_host_direcory
```

Comment: this won't help as SELinux _IS_ disabled